# How can I provide an own implementation of HttpAuthenticationMechanism in Open Liberty

Tags: open-liberty

In a simple app that I run on **Open Liberty 21.0.0.8**, I have provided an implementation of `HttpAuthenticationMechanism`:

```
// imports omitted

@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition(
  loginToContinue = @LoginToContinue(
    loginPage = "/login.xhtml",
    errorPage = "",
    useForwardToLogin = false))
@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomAuthenticationMechanism implements HttpAuthenticationMechanism {

  @Inject
  private IdentityStoreHandler identityStoreHandler;

  @Override
  public AuthenticationStatus validateRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                                              HttpServletResponse response,
                                              HttpMessageContext context)  throws AuthenticationException {

    Credential credential = context.getAuthParameters().getCredential();

    if (credential != null) {
      return context.notifyContainerAboutLogin(identityStoreHandler.validate(credential));
    }
    else {
      return context.doNothing();
    }
  }
}
```

I expected Open Liberty to place that implementation of `HttpAuthenticationMechanism` into service.
However, on startup of Open Liberty a `javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException` is thrown:

```
[INFO] [ERROR   ] CWWKS1925E: The deployment for the dsgvo-management.war module in the dsgvo-management application failed because of multiple HttpAuthenticationMechanism implementations: de.knusperfisch.dsgvo.app.security.control.CustomAuthenticationMechanism, com.ibm.ws.security.javaeesec.cdi.beans.CustomFormAuthenticationMechanism. This failure is likely an application packaging issue. Make sure that each module has only one HttpAuthenticationMechanism implementation.
[INFO] [ERROR   ] CWWKZ0004E: An exception occurred while starting the application dsgvo-management. The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
[INFO] Exception 0 :
[INFO] javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: CWWKS1925E: The deployment for the dsgvo-management.war module in the dsgvo-management application failed because of multiple HttpAuthenticationMechanism implementations: de.knusperfisch.dsgvo.app.security.control.CustomAuthenticationMechanism, com.ibm.ws.security.javaeesec.cdi.beans.CustomFormAuthenticationMechanism. This failure is likely an application packaging issue. Make sure that each module has only one HttpAuthenticationMechanism implementation.
[INFO]  at com.ibm.ws.security.javaeesec.cdi.extensions.JavaEESecCDIExtension.verifyConfiguration(JavaEESecCDIExtension.java:893)
[INFO]  at com.ibm.ws.security.javaeesec.cdi.extensions.JavaEESecCDIExtension.afterBeanDiscovery(JavaEESecCDIExtension.java:173)
```

The Java EE Security API states that:

> An application MAY supply its own HttpAuthenticationMechanism, if desired.

and:

> An HttpAuthenticationMechanism must be a CDI bean, and is therefore
> visible to the container through CDI if it is packaged in a bean
> archive, which generally include Java EE modules and application
> archives [...]
>
> It MUST be possible for the definition of an
> HttpAuthenticationMechanism to exist within the application archive
> [...]

Is there a way in Open Liberty to configure a specific `HttpAuthenticationMechanism` for an app from an application archive, and if so, how is this done?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, as the error message indicates, looks like there are multiple HttpAuthMechanisms active which is not allowed. Are there are any apps that are using the @CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition annotation which would bring in the default com.ibm.ws.security.javaeesec.cdi.beans.CustomFormAuthenticationMechanism AuthMech in addition to your CustomAuthenticationMechanism ?

Comment: Indeed I forgot the `@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition`, which I've added now. Thanks for pointing that out. But that obviously doesn't solve the problem with the multiple implementations of `HttpAuthenictaionMechanism`, because that's a problem within the context of CDI. In Payara, it's possible to configure the `HttpAuthenticationMechanism` with the context parameter `fish.payara.security.mechanism` in `web.xml`. I'm looking for a similar mechanism for Open Liberty.

Comment: As per the current JSR 375 spec we support only one HttpAuthMech but wrt to supporting multiple auth mechanisms in an EAR (or even in a WAR) we have ways to support that currently using specific configuration. As per as the Jakarta/Java EE Servlet spec, we do support the Basic, Form and Certificate login at the web.xml level. In addition, we also support OIDC/JWT, OAuth2, SPENGO, Various Social Logins (Google, Facebook, GitHub, LinkedIn etc), custom (TAI) at a more fine grain level in the same web app (requestURL, User-Agent, host etc) using the AuthenticationFilter (authFilter) configuration

Comment: Clarification - The custom authentication using TAI (Trust Association Interceptor) is a separate configuration - not tied with authFilter